# Getting Country, State, City From FacebookSDK for iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get a user's country, state and city using an `FBGraphObject`. The returned `FBGraphObject` contains the following piece of information:

```
hometown = {
    id = 112118618814985;
    name = "La Paz, Bolivia";
};
```

(My city is called La Paz, in the country Bolivia).

This *could* work wonderfully, if it actually would return the "state". If someone from Wichita, Kansas in the USA, ran my app, the result would be:

```
hometown = {
    name = "Wichita, Kansas";
};
```

(That person's city is Wichita, in the State of Wichita, which is in the USA... The problem is the `FBGraphObject` doesn't tell me, this is in the USA).

When I first saw the graph object's hometown property, I immediately thought I could work with it if I just splat the string using the coma token, to get this:

```
La Paz
Bolivia
```

Then I'd immediately know that the first object represents a city, and the second one represents a country.

But for a country like the USA, while the first element would still represent a city, the second one represents an state, and therefore, I can't store the data tokenized from there.

How could I properly get a country, state, city using the FacebookSDK for iOS? I'm scratching my head because everyone who managed to do it seemed to get it to work with PHP, but I need this to work on the iPhone itself.

EDIT: For the record, this is how I'm trying to get everything:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(error == nil)
    {
        FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser, FBGraphLocation> *graph = result;
        NSLog(@"%@", graph);

        [[SPAccount sharedAccount] linkFacebookAccountWithGraphObject:graph
         andCompletionBlock:^(BOOL linked) {}];
    }
}];
```

And all of the following return `nil`:

```
graph.location.country
graph.country
graph.location.location.country
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the location through the location property on FBGraphUser. This will give you an object that conforms to FBGraphPlace. The location property on the FBGraphPlace conformer is an object that conforms to the FBGraphLocation protocol, which has properties such as:

```
city
country
latitude
longitude
state
street
zip
```

or

**import FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h in your code**

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                  switch (state) {
                                      case FBSessionStateOpen:
                                          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {

                                                    NSLog(@"error:%@",error);


                                              }
                                              else
                                              {                                                   
                                                  // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user birthday:%@",user.birthday);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user location:%@",user.location);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user username:%@",user.username);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user gender:%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"email id:%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"location:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                                                                         user.location[@"name"]]);

                                              }
                                          }];
                                          break;

                                      case FBSessionStateClosed:
                                      case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                                          [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                                          break;

                                      default:
                                          break;
                                  }

                              } ];
```